# flex fallback Testing with with IE11 Emulator

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

As I want to use flex-box I need a fallback and I like to make fallbacks as simple as possible.

I just use 2 `display`properies as described here: http://maddesigns.de/flexbox-fallbacks-2670.html

```
.the-flextable {
    display: table; /* Fallback IE<9 */
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}
```

To test it I have only an IE11 and use the Emulation to set it back to IE9.
With this test scenario this simple fallback does not work. **the emulated IE9 still takes the `display: flex` property**, but then does not display anything.

In a real IE9 the fallback does work!

Now I wonder why it takes the `display: flex`. Is it bacause it is still an IE11 that would take that property, but the IE9 emulation cant rendet it then?

Comment: Indeed, use an official [virtual machine](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). Compatibility modes do not behave exactly as corresponding emulated versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing Document Mode: IE9 should be enough. Even though the DOM Explorer shows IE as trying to do display: flex, it won't render that properly and the fallback rule should take effect.

Comment: I was able to test it on a real IE9 and the fallback works. With Document Mode: IE9 it does not. I will rewrite my question a bit.